# Regular Expression gets everything that matches it and everything that doesn't into lists

Tags: regex, forms, winforms

I'm trying to get all of the regular expression selections inside of a `RichTextBox`, and I want to change the colors for certain keywords. It works. However, when I have a word that is a part of another, it keeps highlighting the original one. When I delete the whole thing, that spot stays that color.

I need some way to store every value that the regular expression searcher went through and didn't match, and select it all using the `RichTextBox`, and change the color. I have no clue as to how to do this. I tried the `^` keyword, but that didn't do anything. Here are my algorithms in case you need them:

I declare the dictionary with every regex value with the corresponding colors here:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Color> regexList = new Dictionary<string, Color>()
{
    {"in", Color.Red},            {"and", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"end", Color.Red},           {"include", Color.CadetBlue},
    {"repeat", Color.AliceBlue},  {"break", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"false", Color.AliceBlue},   {"local", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"return", Color.AliceBlue},  {"do", Color.Red},
    {"for", Color.Red},           {"nil", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"then", Color.AliceBlue},    {"else", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"function", Color.AliceBlue},{"not", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"true", Color.Green},        {"elseif", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"if", Color.AliceBlue},      {"or", Color.AliceBlue},
    {"until", Color.AliceBlue},   {"while", Color.AliceBlue},
    // Containers
    { "\"(.*)\"", Color.Yellow},
};
```

This is called every time the text changes for the `RichTextBox`.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string str in regexList.Keys)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex(str);

        int index = TextField.SelectionStart;
        TextField.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 226, 226);
        foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(TextField.Text))
        {
            TextField.Select(m.Index, m.Value.Length);
            TextField.SelectionColor = regexList[str];
            TextField.SelectionStart = index;
            TextField.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 226, 226);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll be checking this, and updating it as much as possible. I just need some way of selecting everything that isn't caught by the regular expressions and changing their colors.

EDIT

The solution I found (this problem's solution was supposed to syntax highlight the text box) was to just use Scintilla.Net. For those of you who checked this post expecting an answer and need to highlight syntax, here's the [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=scintillanet) to their main page. My manual method would've taken way too long to get all of the keywords in, so this worked nicely.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "...it keeps highlighting the original one"? Can you give an example to clarify?

Comment: I got it, Ill close the post if I can